# NoMethodError in Rails while saving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Checks_controller

class Checkscontroller < ApplicationController

    def show
        @check= Tester.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
         @check = Tester.new(check_params)
         @check.save
         redirect_to @check
    end


    def check_params
        params.require(:check).permit(:title, :description)
    end

end
```

I am trying to save the data in 'checks' controller to 'Tester' model, getting `"NoMethodError` in ChecksController#create", undefined method `tester_url' for`#` while trying to save the data to my DB. There seems to be some issue on this line: "redirect_to @check".

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'home/screen'
    resources :checks
    root 'home#screen'
end
```

Comment: Please show your routes.rb file

Comment: Here it is :Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/screen'
  resources :checks

  root 'home#screen'
end

Comment: Please edit your question with it so that it's readable. Also, what's the relationship between your Tester model and Checks?

Comment: I am trying to add data to  Tester model from Checks controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I see this answer got accepted. To anyone else looking at this: PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS WITHOUT A REALLY GOOD REASON.

Ok, so since you want to use the ChecksController for your Tester model, you'll have to add this to your routes: note that I'm assuming that you do not have a Check model, since I don't see it anywhere and youre using Tester as a check?

```
resources :testers, as: 'checks' controller: 'checks'
```

This line will make it so that `/checks/1` goes to a `Tester` object with ID: 1, and use the `ChecksController` `show` method to show it

---

Old answer, for posterity

You're getting this error because you're missing routes for your Tester model in your `routes.rb` file.

You could add `resources :testers` to it and it will work. Of course you also already need AT LEAST your TestersController to exist with a `show` action

This error is occurring because when you `redirect_to @check`, Rails knows it's a Tester object and expects a route called tester to route to `TestersController#show`. It's attempting to use a helper method that rails creates for routes, called `tester_url`

Comment: I was planning to use the "checks" controller to do show action. I am using rails v4.2.1 and I am a beginner following, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller. I am currently stuck at section 5.7, not very sure if I am missing something else.

Comment: @gowthamjs23 Could you edit your original question to explain why you need a Tester object there, then? When are Check objects used? You can't redirect_to a Tester object directly this way without more configuration

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was following the link mentioned above and Tester is refering the class named Tester that is defined in \models\tester.rb.

Comment: Look, your issue is that rails doesn't know how to read this line: `redirect_to @check` because `@check` is a Tester object, for which you don't have any rules for routing. I'm editing to show you how to fix that now.

Comment: @gowthamjs23 Looks like I fixed your issue, but I just need to let you know: this makes NO practical sense. You should be using the correct controllers and models unless you want to show multiple objects on the same controller

Comment: Sure i am planning to redo design. Thanks for the help.